# Access template child elements in angular directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, zui

I'm trying make a directive out of a great [jquery zooming/panning library](https://github.com/florianguenther/zui53). How can I access the elements in my template to initialize the plugin?

The directive looks like this as of now:

```
    directive('zui', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { URL: "@"},
        template: '<div id="zui" ><div id="viewport" ><img ng-src="{{imageURL}}"></div></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.imageURL = URL;

            var zui = new ZUI53.Viewport( document.getElementById('zui') );
            zui.addSurface( new ZUI53.Surfaces.CSS( document.getElementById('viewport') ) );

            var pan_tool = new ZUI53.Tools.Pan(zui);
            zui.toolset.add( pan_tool );
            pan_tool.attach()
        }
    };
}]);
```

Clearly `document.getByID()` is not the best way to accomplish this. What is a better solution? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Getting to the element using `document.getElementById('zui')` is indeed not nice. If you ever had to have two instances of the `zui` directive, it would break.

1. Don't use `id` on the root element. Use a *marker* class
   such as `class="zui"` or a data attribute such as `data-zui`.
2. Using jquery, you can get to your element using `find` like
   this: `element.find('.zui')[0];`.